# Installing Mojave on External Drive from Yosemite?

Tags: macos

How can I install MacOS Mojave on an external drive without updating my internal drive's currently installed OS: Yosemite?

There are a few tutorials floating around but they seem to be out of date, the ones I've found mention running the app store downloader, then opening the contents of the file `Applications/Install macOS Mojave.app`. I've downloaded the Mojave install files via the `Install macOS Mojave.app` but the downloaded files were placed on the target volume instead and don't match the file names that the tutorial lists.

The machine I'm using is a MBP113, on macOS 10.10.5.
It is compatible with macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

Make a USB installer by following [this tutorial](https://www.macworld.com/article/3284378/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-mojave-installer-drive.html).  I would recommend the terminal method as that's the one I have tried and found reliable.  After you have made the installer, boot to it and plug in the external drive that you wan't Mojave installed on (which I'll refer to as the Mojave drive from now on).  Format the Mojave drive as APFS and GUID partition map with Disk Utility.  Finally, install macOS on the Mojave drive.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - the downloader "Install macOS Mojave.app" no longer downloads the installer contents to itself. The app gives: Invalid macOS Installer The selected item does not appear to be a valid macOS Installer. It is lacking the file "Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" when following the instructions in the tutorial.

Comment: It sounds like your "Install macOS Mojave.app" is corrupt.  Try deleting "Install macOS Mojave.app" from your applications folder and redownloading Mojave from the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12). Then follow the tutorial again.

Comment: Apple updated the installer app, it downloads different files to a different location than the old installer.

Comment: Weird.  I can download Mojave just fine.  Did you use the link I posted?

Comment: Yep, the app store downloads "Install macOS Mojave.app" (~23MB) to the Applications folder, but when I run it the rest of the download (~6GB) gets put on the installation target volume. The file names in the 6GB download are different from the ones the old version of the installer would download.